# how to find an integer in a string in which only the preceeding character is known, and there is a max of 2 digits, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string such as

```rb
x = '4x4 @ 32" hjy w/ R43 potter'
```

```rb
x = '4x4 @ 32" hjy w/ R4 26 potter'
```

```rb
x = 'Restful4 4 @ 32" hjy R8 26 potter'
```

I need to get the digits with a preceding `R`, i.e. `43` from the first one, `4` from the second, and `8` from the third one.

A capital R is guaranteed.

I can get it using `index('R')` but that is painful to take care of all of the cases.

I tried match but it did not seem to work. Any ideas?

I tried this:

```
sFind = x.match /(?<name>R \d+) /
debug=debug+sFind[:name].to_s + "\n"
```

debug gives error

Comment: And regarding your examples: there’s a `"` character within the strings (after `@ 32`). You have to either escape it or use other delimiters. Otherwise, it will end the string.

Comment: If it's not asking too much please respond to comments asking for clarification.

Comment: yes the " is escaped. I didnt put it there becuase I wanted to show what the actual string is. my apologies for the confusion

Comment: yes it shoudl return 8 not 4 for the third one. my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there, just remove the whitespace between `R` and `\d+`:

```
x = '4x4 @ 32" hjy w/ R43 potter'

x.match /(?<name>R \d+) / #=> nil
x.match /(?<name>R\d+) /  #=> #<MatchData "R43 " name:"R43">
```

There's also [`String#[]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) which can extract a capture group right away:

```
x[/(?<name>R\d+) /, :name] #=> "R43"
```

To only get the digits:

```
x[/R(?<name>\d+) /, :name] #=> "43"
```

or a little shorter by not using a named capture:

```
x[/R(\d+)/, 1] #=> "43"
```

You can also use a so-called *positive lookbehind* assertion to match digits preceded by `R` without including that `R`:

```
x[/(?<=R)\d+/] #=> "43"
```

Comment: what does `<name>` will do?

Comment: @Rajagopalan it's a [named capture](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Named+Captures) group.

Comment: I do not want the R returned though, just the 4 or 43

Comment: @jay if you don’t want to capture `R`, move it out of the capture group, e.g. `/R(?<name>\d+) /`

Answer (score 1):

Use scan method

```
x = "4x4 @ 32 hjy w/ R43 potter"
matches = x.scan(/R(\d{1,2})/)
puts matches.flatten.first
```

If there are multiple R followed by numbers like this, then remove the `.first`

```
x = "4x4 @ 32 hjy w/ R43 potter R4 26 potter"
matches = x.scan(/R(\d{1,2})/)
p matches.flatten
```

Output

```
"43"
["43", "4"]
```